# Acer laptop possibly wrong bios flash, what now?

Tags: bios, flashing

the title says it all, can this be repaired?

I was allways learnt that a mis flashed bios is a lost case, but that was 12 years ago, is there something changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to investigate this with Acer, but some motherboards have a protected base BIOS version and include a button or jumper on the motherboard which will reset the BIOS to that "clean" version.  It's worth contacting the support for both Acer and the motherboard manufacturer to see if this is the case.  If it isn't, then yea, you're pretty hosed.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from opening up the chip, doing a bunch of hardware mods, and reflashing manually, I would say you are stuck. Sorry :(